# namespace conflict in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have the following C++ classes.

xyz.h

```
class xyz {
public:
    static int abc();
};
```

qwe.h

```
#include xyz.h

namespace xyz {

class qwe{
public:
    void bnm() {
        int value = xyz::abc();

    }
};

}
```

How do I access `xyz::abc()` here. I get a compilation error here saying `abc` is not a member of `xyz`. I understand the reason that it's trying to search for the `abc` method inside this `xyz` namespace whereas what it should ideally get is a static method in the `xyz` class.

Is there a way to get around this without changing the namespace names?

Comment: What happens if you use a namespace alias before defining the class? `namespace xyz xyzns;` should cause `xyzns` to become an alias for the `xyz` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make a class with the same name as a namespace (or its own namespace for that matter).

Comment: well thanks but the code is already written by someone else and i am just trying to append my line or code.

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case there is no direct solution. Altough C++ has a concept of `elaborated type specifier`, in particular:

```
xyz       ab;   // The defn is ambiguous.
class xyz ab;   // The ambiguity is resolved.
```

You can aslo try this:

```
class xyz dummy;
int value = dummy.abc();
```

C++ allows calling static methods using syntax of the instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

In the special case that the file `xyz.h` is really simple and depend on little else, you can do this:

```
namespace othername {
   #include "xyz.h"
}
```

and then use

```
othername::xyz::abc();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace hack = xyz;
hack::abc();
```